# System Verilog subtraction removing important bits

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, hdl, vivado

I have a simple subtraction of two 32-bit numbers which I know will never result in a number larger then 25-bit. After elaborating my design is see that the tool (Xilinx Vivado 2018.1) has trimmed the input registers down to 25-bit which will cause incorrect values to be calculated.

```
logic [31:0] ain;
logic [31:0] bin;
logic [24:0] cout;

assign cout = ain - bin;
```

this results in an elaborated design with an rtl_sub like this...
[image: bad_subtraction]

After referencing the LRM and some other questions on the subject I feel that this should work by subtracting the two larger numbers and then truncating the result but maybe I am misunderstanding the coding rules?

I additionally tried this which also did NOT work

```
assign cout = 32'(ain - bin);
```

Can someone please recommend the most appropriate way to code this?

Comment: If the result is 25 bits only, the upper 7 bits will have no influence on the result, thus the result is correct. May be different if you are working with signed values.

Comment: Please confirm: the numbers can be 32 bits but there is a correlation between `ain` and `bin` so the result of the subtraction is always <=25 bits.

Comment: yes, I KNOW based on the design that the result of ain - bin will NEVER exceed a number that can fit in 25bits.

Comment: As @HansLehnert says:  In that case when the numbers appear at the input of your subtractor the MS bits MUST be the same and thus can be ignored. So where does the "which will cause incorrect values to be calculated." come from?

Comment: Give us an example of incorrect results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2's complement subtraction

```
C = A -B
```

is the same as

```
C = A + ~B + 1
```

There's no way bits [31:25] can have an affect on the result of bits [24:0]. Maybe your assumption about the answer fitting in 25 bits is incorrect.

Comment: I have come to realize that yes indeed bits [31:25] will not matter and that the elaborated design is correct as it stands. Thank you all for clearing this up, guess it's just been too long since I practiced my basic binary math.